# Null appearing at the end of for loop output in r

Tags: r, for-loop, null

```
for (i in 1:9){

  print(cat(replicate(i,"*"),"", replicate((9-i),'*')))

}

Output:

*  * * * * * * * *NULL
* *  * * * * * * *NULL
* * *  * * * * * *NULL
* * * *  * * * * *NULL
* * * * *  * * * *NULL
* * * * * *  * * *NULL
* * * * * * *  * *NULL
* * * * * * * *  *NULL
* * * * * * * * *  NULL
```

how to remove the null.

Comment: Try using 10-i instead of 9-i

Answer (score 0):

Remove `print` statement and use `\n` for new line.

```
for (i in 1:9){
  cat(replicate(i,"*"),"", replicate((9-i),'*'), '\n')
}

*  * * * * * * * * 
* *  * * * * * * * 
* * *  * * * * * * 
* * * *  * * * * * 
* * * * *  * * * * 
* * * * * *  * * * 
* * * * * * *  * * 
* * * * * * * *  * 
* * * * * * * * *
```